# How to import zebra package in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import

I tried to import this `packages`:

```
import com.zebra.sdk.comm.ConnectionException;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.discovery.BluetoothDiscoverer;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.discovery.DiscoveredPrinter;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.discovery.DiscoveredPrinterBluetooth;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.discovery.DiscoveryHandler;
```

But gives me an `error` that it cannot find them. Any help please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to add zebra sdk in android project to import all above classes

Answer (score 9):

you need to add dependency of zebra sdk follow below steps

1. Download this jar file  https://github.com/luisamilcarr/zebra_zq510/raw/master/app/libs/ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar
2. Cut and copy this jar file from download folder to android libs folder
3. In build.gradle folder, add below line in dependencies section

```
implementation files('libs/ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar')
```

4. sync the project
   That's all

***Hint:*** Main source https://github.com/luisamilcarr/zebra_zq510

Comment: We are going to use this jar in commerical product. So is this jar is open source ?

Answer (score -2):

**download official library  documentation**

[ZEBRA > LINK-OS MULTIPLATFORM SDK DOWNLOADS & SUPPORT](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/printer-software/link-os-multiplatform-sdk.html)

here all library for all platforms
include ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar